Sums of characters over over partitions of equal length
Let $\chi^{\lambda}$ and $\chi^{\mu}$ be irreducible characters of the symmetric group $S_n$. Their inner product satisfies $\langle \chi^{\lambda}, \chi^{\mu}\rangle =\sum_{\nu} \frac{1}{z_{\nu}} \chi^{\lambda}(\nu)\chi^{\mu}(\nu)=\delta_{\lambda \mu}$. Here, the sum is taken over all partitions of $n$ and $z_{\nu}$ is the size of the centralizer of a permutation of conjugacy class $\nu$. I'm interested in the summation $$f_k(\lambda, \mu)=\sum_{\ell(\nu)=k} \frac{1}{z_{\nu}} \chi^{\lambda}(\nu)\chi^{\mu}(\nu),$$ taken over partitions of $n$ with $k$ parts. I have a basic understanding of how to express these sums in terms of other (equally complicated) quantities. But I was wondering if the sums $f_k(\lambda, \mu)$ have been studied in any way. Thanks

Just curious, why are you interested in the summations? How did you encounter them? Or did you just decide that these might be fun sums to examine? Just in case you have some concrete reason to find these nice, it might help answerers with finding a satisfying answer to your question.
